# Connection between Proximal Algorithm and Tikhonov Regularization

Tags: convergence-divergence, optimization, convex-optimization, regularization

Consider the following minimization problem:
$$\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{f(x)},$$
where f is a proper convex closed function such that there exists at least one solution of the above-mentioned problem.
Proximal point algorithm works choosing an initial point $x_0$ and the minimizing sequence is defined recursively by $$x_k=\arg\,\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{f(x)+\frac{1}{2a_k}{\lVert x-x_{k-1}\rVert}}^2,\quad \text{for any }k\in \mathbb{N}.$$

In Tikhonov regularization the $n$-th term of the minimizing sequence is defined by
$$\bar{x}_k=\arg\,\min_{x\in \mathbb{R}^n}{f(x)+\frac{1}{2a_k}\lVert x\rVert}^2, \quad \text{for any }k\in \mathbb{N}.$$

My question is: if I choose $x_0=0$ in proximal algorithm, does the limit of the sequence  $(x_k)_k$ coincide with the limit of  $(\bar{x}_k)_k$?

I suppose not but I cannot provide an example.

Comment: Proximal point looks like it wants to encourage proximity : punish large steps in solution space in case the local approximation is not very good or the function is very fast varying non linear. Preserving the condition for the principle of continuation to be reasonable. Tikhonov is just ordinary regularization over all variables preventing them to differ from 0 too much.

Comment: If you choose $x_0 = 0$ it will just mean that you start searching for an optimum from origo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer this intuitively.
The simple answer is no.

The intuitive reasoning is that the Proximal Point algorithm should converge to the same solution as Gradient Descent solution would converge to.
They only differ in the path they create to get there.

While the Tikhonov Regularization creates a completely different solution.

Actually they match in the case the series of $ {a}_{k} $ goes to zero in the Tikhonov Case.